# Angular 2 - Dynamically change an after CSS element

Tags: css, angular

We are working on a workflow element in our web application, but running into problems trying to update background colors to indicate completion.  The Workflow bar is a rectangle with a sideways triangle on the right.  The triangle is a psuedo-element built through CSS, something like:

```
.navwizard > li > a:after { 
    ....
    background-color:#eeeeee,
    ....
}
```

We want to update the background color after a status change to indicate success, but I'm not sure how to do this in the scope of Angular 2.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could define another class and [toggle that class](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) depending on the completion status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could apply a success class to your .navwizard element after completion

```
.navwizard.success > li > a:after {
    background-color: green;
}
```

you could apply this class with the ngClass directive https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to this element on success with angular and create a css block like this.

`.navwizard > li > a.success:after {
background-color: #000;
}`

Remembering that javascript is "only" for manipulating elements. Customization should stay with css whenever possible